# Bash parameter substituiton within commands

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution, variable-substitution

I have a passing understanding of [Parameter Substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), including substrings like so

```
foo="Hello World";
greeting=${foo:0:6}
```

But do I do this with commands?

```
greeting="Hello"
md5greeting=$(echo $greeting | md5sum :0:6)
>>b1946a
```

Where the output is the first 6 characters of the md5sum of the 'hello'.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `echo "$greeting" | md5sum | cut -c 1-6` would work if you know the output will only be a single line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter substitution doesn't work like that, at least not in bash. You need a real variable (parameter) and directly operate on it. So for example like that:

```
var=$(echo abcdefgh | cmd1 | cmd2 | ... )
var2="${var:2:4}"
```

The exception is `zsh` where you can convert command substitution to parameter "on the fly" and do above in one line:

```
var2=${"$(echo abcdefgh | cdm1 | cmd2 | ... )":2:4}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that:

```
echo $greeting | md5sum
```

Or more reliably:

```
printf '%s\n' "$greeting" | md5sum
```

Does not give you the MD5 hash of the content of the variable, but of the content of the variable followed by a newline character. For the MD5 hash of the content of the variable:

```
printf %s "$greeting" | md5sum
```

For the first 6 bytes of it, with some `head` implementations:

```
printf %s "$greeting" | md5sum | head -c 6
```

or more portably:

```
printf %s "$greeting" | md5sum | dd bs=1 count=6 2> /dev/null
```